# Excel 365 VBA Union not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba, union

I have three non-contiguous Ranges (a, b, d) combined in a Union. Each Range is 11 rows and one column. There are a number of protected cells in the column between each range. To confirm I've assigned the correct rows for each range I used the MsgBox c. Address, and it displays the correct row and column numbers for each range.

When I try to transfer data in, the transfer fails when the Union attempts to put data in Range B. The error is basically 'your trying to copy into a protected cell.'
a,b,c,and d are DDim as Range.

One thing I tried was to try and find the lastrow in the range. There was data in Range a but the return was 0. Here's the code that's returning the error.

```
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

Worksheets(wsSh).Activate 'Whippets
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q158")
    Set rngB = .Find(strStake, LookIn:=xlValues)
    secondaddress = rngB.Address
    .Range(rngB.Address).Offset(4, -8).Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    Set a = .Range(.Range(secondaddress).Offset(4, -8),.Range(secondaddress).Offset(15, -8))
    Set b = .Range(.Range(secondaddress).Offset(27, -8), .Range(secondaddress).Offset(38, -8))
    Set d = .Range(.Range(secondaddress).Offset(50, -8), .Range(secondaddress).Offset(61, -8))
    Set c = Union(a, b, d)
    MsgBox c.Address
    Stop
    With c 'Set range for stake
        Set rngE = .Find(strRegNo, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Look for current Reg No
        If rngE Is Nothing Then 'No match found, enter new dog
            intB = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(c)
            ActiveCell.Offset(intB, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.Value2 = strRegNo
        Else:
            'Match found, dog already entered
            GoTo Next_Loop
        End If
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thank for fixing the code format. I finally learned how to do that.